# dataframe - find common phrases in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this

```
df a
name     |  list_of_skills
---------------------------
brian    | ['coding in python', 'halo 3']
jon      | ['coding in python', 'running', 'sports']
```

Is there a way I can get some counts of the most common phrases like this:

```
'coding in python'    2
'halo 3'              1
'running'             1
'sports'              1
```

Just a simple phrase counter without iterating through each list and comparing it to all the other ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df['list_of_skills'].explode().value_counts()
print (s)
coding in python    2
running             1
sports              1
halo 3              1
Name: list_of_skills, dtype: int64
```

If need DataFrame:

```
df1 = s.rename_axis('words').reset_index(name='counts')
print (df1)
              words  counts
0  coding in python       2
1           running       1
2            sports       1
3            halo 3       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`Groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
In [254]: df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['brian', 'john'], 'list_of_skills':[['coding in python', 'halo 3'], ['coding in python', 'running', 'sports']]})

In [255]: df
Out[255]: 
    name                       list_of_skills
0  brian           [coding in python, halo 3]
1   john  [coding in python, running, sports]

In [258]: ans = df.explode('list_of_skills').groupby('list_of_skills').size()

In [259]: ans
Out[259]: 
list_of_skills
coding in python    2
halo 3              1
running             1
sports              1
dtype: int64
```